# c++ templates in vim

Tags: vim

I downloaded c++ plugin from the official vim site. When I press hotkeys for this plugin vim tells me that there is no an appropriate template. Where I can take the collection of templates for c++? I am a newbie at vim so I cannot write it by myself.

**UPDATE:**

I downloaded [c.vim : C/C++ IDE](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213).

Comment: It would help if you are telling us what plugin you had downloaded... there are several.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least you should read the installation directions in `README.csupport` file in the downloaded `.zip`.

The templates are in the `c-support` directory.

Comment: yes I know, I have "Templates" and other files in c-support/templates directory, but I still have an error: style "idioms.function" / template "idioms.function" not found.

Comment: I press hotkey '\if' which is the item 'function' in menu 'idioms'